# How to develop a Dicom web Viewer

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, silverlight, dicom

I got an assignment to develop a web viewer for DICOM images. As this is a small/ demo project that's why I have not registered in DICOM imaging server. So I am planning to download some sample DICOM images from the net and will start working on them. I have gone through [A service based approach for medical image distribution in healthcare Intranets.

Eleni Kaldoudi, Dimosthenis Karaiskakis][1](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/7357975_A_service_based_approach_for_medical_image_distribution_in_healthcare_Intranets) there it is mentioned about **"DIM web service"**,[image: DIM web service] 
I did not get what is that service. Is that predefined service provided by any third party or DICOM imaging server itself or I have to develop it from the scratch? Even I googled for it and I did not get much help. From the primary investigation I found that, I need below things for my assignment I guess:

1. A technology for developing UI to run in Web browser.( I choose
   Silverlight for this)
2. Few web Services to send request to the server and
   get responses from the server(I choose WCF for this)
3. A web Server to keep some sample DICOM images in my local machine(Apache Tomcat/ IIS
   server)
4. And offcourse a Language for back end coding(C#.Net as I worked on it before
   and I found it most suitable for me).

Can anybody please guide me to find the exact requirement for my assignment or what I wrote above is sufficient for me? Any idea or help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
Please correct me if I am wrong.
As I mentioned in my question I am developing a small demo kind of application. So I am using my local machine as my DICOM imaging server, and that's why I am not bothering about the security and off-course as I am sending/getting both text and image so i think XML format with HTTP/SOAP protocol transmission will be the best for my application. I am not bothering about security and performance for the time being.

Comment: You should take a look at WADO (Web Access to DICOM Objects), an extension to the DICOM standard that was designed for web-based transport of DICOM data (including images).

Comment: Is it in your requirement that using DICOM protocols to make queries to the DICOM server directly is NOT allowed?  Since you've mentioned that this is a small-scale project, i take that there's no need to put a webservice interface in between the client and the server?

Comment: Without any web service how the browser or the client will communicate with the server? Do you have any idea or thoughts, please share them with me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

We are using leadtools HTML5 Zero Footprint DICOM Viewer to display DICOM images from PACS. For more information, see the following link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/397527/HTML5-Zero-Footprint-Viewer-for-DICOM-and-PACS

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out what's your transport strategy and methodology, and since its a image based web transition, you have to figure out the transport protocol.
i supposed the image distribution will be some kind of large size file, i don't recommend to use WCF, since its compression and decompression strategy is very poor and inefficient. You can use socket with customize byte compression schema.

Comment: Sorry I did not get "what's your transport strategy and methodology" I am little new to this and I do not know much about it. Can you please more brief and suggest me some idea,links or code reference for stepwise follow?

Comment: I mean you have to figure out how to transmit your data through the web, like the protocol, security, compression and decompression algorithm, and how to distribute these images. And maybe different web services and request\response strategies take different context of them.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I am developing a small demo kind of application. So I am using my local machine as my DICOM imaging server, and that's why I am not bothering about the security and off-course as I am sending/getting both text and image so i think XML format with HTTP/SOAP protocol transmission will be the best for my application. I am not bothering about security and performance for the time being. Now can you please tell me is that all what you are looking for or do I need to gather some more information?